# Ubuntu server 16.04 не работает копирование и вставка из windows

Tags: windows, ubuntu, vmware

Прочитав справку я нашел это:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

однако, ничего не получается,т.е копирую текст в браузере windows перемещаю курсор в виртуальную машину vmvare и пытаюсь вставить всеми этими комбинациями и ничего/ Я новичок,сильно не пинайте)

Comment: В VirtualBox в настройке конкретной виртуалки есть опция включения и выключения общего буфера обмена. По-умолчанию она выключена. Может у тебя в вмваре тоже выключена? guest tools (virtual drivers) стоят в гостевой машине?

Comment: Прочитал внимательнее. А в `tty` вообще подобное должно работать?

Answer (score 1):

Установи SSH в Ubuntu и подключайся через [putty](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/x86/putty.exe) с Windows.

Для этого надо:

1. Установить SSH **sudo apt-get install ssh**
2. Настроить сеть на виртуалке: в настройках виртуальной машины в сетевых адаптерах выбрать мост через ваш физический сетевой адаптер, для того чтобы Ubuntu была в той же подсети что и Windows.

[image: подключение по SSH]

Копируй и вставляй через Ctrl+C/Ctrl+V сколько душе угодно.